# Send JSON to address and retrieve the response

Tags: java, android, json

This question is a duplicate for sure but I need an answer and can't find it.

I need to send a Json json object to the server and retrieve another json.
What I've tried so far isn't working, nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong?

The json object to send is `userCreate` and the address is `path`, tell me if you really need the adress and json format.

Solved, FINAL CODE:

```
Thread x = new Thread(){
                        public void run(){
                            Looper.prepare();
                            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(path);
                            String result = "";
                            try {        
                                post.setEntity(new StringEntity(userCreate.toString())); 
                                HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);                               
                                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                                result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                                Toast.makeText(ctx,"Result: " + result + " response: " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode(), 10000).show();             
                            } catch(Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            Looper.loop();
                        }
                    };
                    x.start();
```

Comment: `I keep hitting an exception.` first what exception, next google for this exception

Comment: I solved that exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
post.setEntity(new StringEntity(request.toString(), "utf-8")); 
                                // request is the JSONObject
HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
```

Comment: still not working, the same thing is happening

Comment: do I have to use asynk task?

Comment: @MihaiBratulescu yup obvious, use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) or [Volley library](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-volley-library-example/) whenever you need to implement long running tasks.

Comment: ok so I posted my last attempt, but NOTHING happens

Comment: @MihaiBratulescu Until you share exception, no one can help you out.

Comment: there is no exception this time, nothing happens. No toast is being shown.

Comment: then what's the response code you are getting? Check it by `response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()`.

Comment: found something, it never calls doInBackground... any possible reasons for that?

Comment: @MihaiBratulescu Are you sure its not going into Exception? FYI, you can't update UI directly while doing in `doInBackground()` method. Yes you can but that's different scenario.

Comment: I'm sure doInBackground is not called because I already called another asynktask before (forgot about it) so I switched to good old thread and now works I get a result: "no type submitted" :( but I suspect why. thanks for your help

Comment: I can't seem to fix it, I keep getting "no type submitted" == no data entered. Is there a reason why the server is not getting my json code?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me :

```
//MainActivity.java
Pass the name-value pair to server .you can get those values using json-array in PHP.


String registerURL="http:10.0.2.2/register.php";

public void registerUser(String email, String password, String mobile)
 {

    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", register_tag));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mobile", mobile));



 JsonParser.makeHttpRequest(registerURL,"POST",params);




}

//JSONParser.java

public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

// function get json from url
// by making HTTP POST or GET method
public static JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {


    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        // check for request method
        if (method == "POST") {


            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();



        } else if (method == "GET") {


            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        }

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    try {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();


    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {

        jObj = new JSONObject(json);

    } catch (JSONException e) {

    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
}
```

Comment: I need to send a json object to the server first

Comment: @Mihai Bratulescu  I have edited  my answer .This code will help you to send data over server.

Comment: thank a lot I think it will work because it looks a bit different from the others but I'm confused about some java thing: List<NameValuePair> params I can post anything here right? can I make this to be a json object?

Comment: there is no return statement, what do I return?

Comment: @Mihai Bratulescu Now your idea will get clear. No need to make json object you can simply pass your data using namevalue pair.

Comment: oh, I understood that you dont send json but add a string to the url. I've converted is to a string and got "no type submitted" with code 200. The problem is the server guy is unreachable for the last 2 days and since I'm an intern here I dont know if I've sent wrong json format input or is there a possibility that there are some filter or I dont know what (not my domain I'm just the android guy) that the server cant read the json correctly cause all the examples I've tried had the same result (i hope you understand what I mean).

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(path);
post.setEntity(new StringEntity(request.toString(), "utf-8"));
HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
```

Hop this will help.

Comment: unfortunately no, I've added my new code version and it does nothing

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
// General query of the website. Takes an object of type Q and returns one of class R.
public static <Q extends JSONObject, R> R query(String urlBase, String op, Q q, Class<R> r) throws IOException {
  // Prepare to post.
  final HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(urlBase + op);

  if (q != null) {
    // Get it all into a JSON string.
    final StringEntity input = new StringEntity(asJSONString(q));
    input.setContentType("application/json");
    postRequest.setEntity(input);
  }
  log.debug("> " + urlBase + op + (q == null ? "" : " " + q));
  // Post it and wait.
  return readResponse(postRequest, HttpClientPool.getClient().execute(postRequest), r);
}
```